# RichFaces error - javax.faces.FacesException: Can't parse configuration file

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, tomcat7

I am getting the below error while server start up. I am trying to learn RichFaces, below are my system configurations.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.GlassFishConfigureListener
javax.faces.FacesException: Can't parse configuration file: jar:file:/D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/lib/richfaces-components-ui-4.3.7.Final.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml: Error at line 2 column 325: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'faces-config'.
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.parse(ConfigureListener.java:1751)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:496)
    at com.sun.faces.config.GlassFishConfigureListener.contextInitialized(GlassFishConfigureListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4971)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Tomcat - apache-tomcat-7.0.54

RichFaces - 4.3.7

Jars in tomcat lib -

```
annotations-api.jar
catalina-ant.jar
catalina-ha.jar
catalina-tribes.jar
catalina.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
ecj-P20140317-1600.jar
el-api.jar
guava-r08.jar
jasper-el.jar
jasper.jar
jsf-api-2.0.jar
jsf-impl-1.2.jar
jsp-api.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
org.apache.commons.io.jar
richfaces-components-api-4.3.7.Final.jar
richfaces-components-ui-4.3.7.Final.jar
richfaces-core-api-4.3.7.Final.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.3.7.Final.jar
servlet-api.jar
tomcat-api.jar
tomcat-coyote.jar
tomcat-dbcp.jar
tomcat-i18n-es.jar
tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
tomcat-jdbc.jar
tomcat-util.jar
tomcat7-websocket.jar
websocket-api.jar
```

Faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
 version="2.0">
</faces-config>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
 <display-name>JSF Webapp</display-name>
<context-param>
 <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
 <param-value>server</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
 <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
 <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
 <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
 <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
 <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
 <param-value>enable</param-value>
 </context-param>

<listener>
 <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

<!-- Faces Servlet -->
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Please let me know what i ma doing wrong.

Comment: maybe something is not properly deployed. Did you tried redeploying your application? (clean, publish..)

Comment: Yes. I did try clean and publish. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Can you add same version for jsf-impl.jar, I mean jsf-impl-2.0.jar

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, how you got rid of the issue. I also faced the same issue. I removed the the below entry and it worked.

```
<listener>
 <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
```

Since you are using JSF 1.2 and higher and Tomcat higher than v7.0.42, the above entry is not required.